# While loop with scan in C

Tags: c, while-loop, infinite-loop

So my question is the following.

```
int n=0;
while(n<=0)
    scanf("%d",&n);
```

This code enters in an infinite loop, and I don't have a clue why. When the user inputs a number > 0, the loop was supposed to stop.

And thanks:)

Comment: The code may never enter the loop at all - since `n` is uninitialized. How do you know it's looping? Did you type a number and press ENTER?

Comment: I just compiled this and when I enter the value 1 and hit enter, it exits the loop. I think your problem lies elsewhere in your program. You could try making `n` a `volatile int` just to make sure you aren't getting an optimization problem.

Comment: I *very* much doubt the issue is caused by the optimizer and `volatile` won't fix it.

Comment: Ok i dont know what is a volatile int, but i already created a new file with only this code to try it alone, still same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should change your compiler because i'm getting the fine result.

You might have a problem somewhere else.

You can check here.:

http://ideone.com/C4Yobi

Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
main( )
{
int n = 0;
while (n <= 0)
    scanf("%d",&n);
printf("%d",n);
}

Input:
-5
4
Output:
4
```

Comment: Ok sorry for the trouble, and thanks a lot. I will talk with my teacher tomorrow, it seems to be a problem of gcc.

Comment: It's unlikely (actually *impossible*) that it's a problem with `gcc`.

Comment: @NikBougalis i'm agree with you because i tried with the same compiler.:)

Comment: So i really dont know, maybe how i call the gcc? i am doing the following command on the ubuntu terminal "gcc -o test1 test1.c"

Answer (score 4):

Over and over and over and over...

`stdin` is (generally) line-buffered - one has to press `<enter>` to make the terminal transfer the characters to your program. So now there's a dangling newline character in the buffer, and `scanf()` will try to read it during the next iteration, but it's not an integer, so it fails and doesn't change the contents of the variable. To solve this, make `scanf()` eat the newline:

```
scanf("%d\n", &number);
```

(Oh yes, `n` is also used uninitialized, but it seems that your code enters the loop anyway, so that's not the issue. **Do initialize it,** though, else you **will** face other strange errors.)

Comment: @user2116077 Having deduced from the quality of this answer (sorry, but...) - you may have other problems/semantic errors/undefined behaviors in your code. Check for those as well.

Comment: @H2CO3 in c++ it's UB but is this true in case of c?

Comment: You already tried what? Typing a number and pressing ENTER? Eating the newline? You aren't helping us help you...

Comment: this is my first post, i am kinda confused sorry if i am not helpful xD I already tried typing and pressing enter, yes.

Comment: i mean is this program lead to ub as in c++.

Comment: @Arpit Of course it does. Reading uninitialized variables is UB.

Comment: i have it initialized in the program, it was a typo in the question, sorry

Comment: @H2CO3  "scanf() will try to read it during the next iteration, but it's not an integer, so it fails and doesn't change the contents of the variable"
it seems wrong to me. i just use the same code to read 10 ints and it works fine without using `\n` .

http://ideone.com/3ez7mY

Answer (score 1):

```
while (n <= 0)
    // something
```

means *"do something while value of `n` is less or equal to `0`"*. Just make sure that `n` is initialized when condition `n <= 0` is being evaluated. Using uninitialized variables produces **undefined behavior**.

You should do:

```
int n = 0;
while (n <= 0)
    scanf("%d\n",&n);
```

Comment: yes, i know, so when the scan gets a n>10, it should stop right?

Comment: @user2116077 It should, certainly - see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you claim to have tried things and they didn't work (although I don't see why) let's try something else. Let's use a programmer's best friend: `printf`. How about trying to run this code instead:

```
int n = 0;

while(n <= 0)
{
    printf("Please enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d\n", &n);
    printf("I see you entered: %d\n", n);
}

printf("Done with the loop. The value of n is: %d\n", n);
```

This will let you see what the computer is doing and what values it reads as it reads them. Try replacing your code with the above and let's see what happens.

Comment: Now it stops after i do a second enter,which is better.

Comment: Please enter a number: 5
2
I see you entered: 5
Done with the loop. The value of n is: 5

Comment: Right. So it works correctly. You entered 5 and it read 5 and *correctly* exited the loop since 5 is not zero and positive. So what's the problem?

Comment: i had to input the 2, so it exited the loop.

Comment: Did you enter 5 and press enter?

Comment: Yes. enter 5, press enter, then enter 2, press enter.

Comment: And what happens if you don't enter 2 and press ENTER?

Comment: it just does nothing,but when I put a number and press enter it exit.